# Why does the OpenTBS_DOWNLOAD command is not generating a file

Tags: odt, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am new to openTBS,
I tried the html and php code from 'https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo' and 'https://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/demo/demo_merge.php', and I can't manage to get the "`$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD)`" command working :
I get a page with chinese characters and no file is being downloaded.
Sample of the page :

```
PK鸙_S^�2''mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK鸙_SConfigurations2/popupmenu/PK鸙_SConfigurations2/floater/PK鸙_S'Configurations2/accelerator/current.xmlPKPK鸙_SConfigurations2/images/Bitmaps/PK鸙_SConfigurations2/menubar/PK鸙_SConfigurations2/progressbar/PK鸙_SConfigurations2/statusbar
```

The `$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE)` command is working and a merged odt file is saved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add an `exit()` after the ̀`$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE)`  ?

Comment: I have `exit()` at the end of the script.

Comment: try with `exit()` just after  ̀`$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE)`